# In an Android Junit5/Mockito test, how to inject a very specific dummy (integer) field into a Spy or Mock object?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, mockito, junit5

The scenario here is that there is a hidden field in the Android class being referenced in the app. At runtime on a real device that's never a problem however because the app runs with elevated privileges("android.uid.system") so the field is always accessible.

In a JUnit5 test however, references to that same field will break the unit test because the field simply does not exist in the testrunner environment.

```
/**
 * A method in my Java app that's being tested
 * 
 * The argument has a hidden integer field accessible only at runtime. The app runs fine at runtime 
 * because the APK always runs with elevated privileges (android.uid.system) on the real device.
 * However in the JUnit runtime, the field remains inaccessible
 *
 */
static void methodInMyApplication(DataProcessor dataProcessObj){

    dataProcessObj.hiddenInteger = 5;   // this field only exists during runtime on the device

}


/**
 * Junit 5 test written in Kotlin
 *
 */
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension::class)    // JUnit5 annotation
class WifiUnitTests {

    @Spy
    private val spyDataProccessor: DataProcessor = DataProcessor()
    
    @Test
    fun testMyJavaMethod() {
        MyApp.methodInMyApplication(spyDataProccessor)  // test crashes here because "hiddenInteger" field does not exist
    
    }
    
}
```

Does anyone know of a way to manually inject that hidden integer field into a spy(or mock) object before making the method call to the application?
I already tried the **setField()** function in org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils but it doesn't exist. Seems that function is available in Spring Framework but not in junit commons.

Comment: Is DataProcessor a class you control? Is `methodInMyApplication` the method you are trying to test in `testMyJavaMethod`?

Comment: @JeffBowman No, I have no access to the source code of DataProcessor, I just import its reference into my code. Yes "methodInMyApplication" is what's being tested.